# margin left and right not working correct in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm testing designed page with CSS and html with different browser. When I test with chrome page working correct , but not working correct in Firefox. I didn't use strange style, Just used the margin , padding and border radius. I don't know why not working. Thanks for guiding.

```
background-color: #7B618F;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
margin-right: 2px;
margin-left: 2px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
```

[in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hOmo.png)

[in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGQVM.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you please add some HTML?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9d2nqpom/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes, I think it's a bug. I was using chrome and I had this type of problem so I switched to edge and firefox but sometime later it was also not working. But after rebooting my pc everything was okay.

Comment: I did that, but not change. I also tested with the colleagues system.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9d2nqpom/

Answer (score 0):

I find solution for this problem. It's problem for right to left direction used in CSS style , when I use dir in division tag working correct in Firefox.
[resolved](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvebg97r/2/)

`<div class="h-left" dir="rtl">`